# javascript converting ints to strings when I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have some experience coding in a few other languages, but I am very new to Javascript.
I am trying to first generate an array of consecutive integers, and then using a separate function sum up the contents of the array. I am able to generate the array no problem, but when I try to sum the contents the elements of the array are inexplicably converted to strings. I can't make heads or tails of why this is happening.

Any and all help or advice is appreciated. Thanks.

```
// Takes a starting and ending number, and returns an array of every step between.

function range(start, end, step = 1) {
    let iterator = start;
    let array = new Array();
    while(iterator <= end) {
        array.push(iterator);
        iterator += step;
    }
    return array;
}

// Takes an array and calculates the sum of the contents.

function sum(...inputs) {
    let total = 0;
    if(inputs[0] instanceof Array) {     // Test whether the input array is single or multi dimensional
        for(input in inputs[0]) {
            console.log(typeof(input));             // Evaluates to String?????? <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            console.log(inputs[0] instanceof Array); // Evaluates to true
            console.log(typeof inputs[0][0]);       // Evaluates to Number

            total += input;
        }
    }
    else {
        for(input in inputs) {
            total += input; // I want this to add numbers together, but it concatenates strings instead.
        }
    }

    return total;        // I want this to return a number, but it returns a string.
}

console.log(sum(range(1,10)));  // Returns string literal "00123456789"
```

Comment: Tip: you can sum an array like this: `array.reduce((a, b) => a + b)`

Comment: Thanks! That is really cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> for(input in inputs[0]) {
> ```

This loops over the **property names** of an object, which for an array are the strings `"0"`, `"1"`, etc.

Use `of` to loop over the values (which are the numbers you put into the array).

Comment: Thanks! I cannot believe I got all this help so quickly. You people rock!

Answer (score 1):

So I did a bit of digging and it seems the issue is coming from the for in loop usage. So for in iterates over keys rather than values if we want to iterate over values we can use the for of loop as shown bellow:

```js
function range(start, end, step = 1) {
    let iterator = start;
    let array = new Array();
    while(iterator <= end) {
        array.push(iterator);
        iterator += step;
    }
    return array;
}

// Takes an array and calculates the sum of the contents.

function sum(...inputs) {
    let total = 0;
    if(inputs[0] instanceof Array) {             
       for(input of inputs[0]) {
            console.log(typeof(input));  
            console.log(inputs[0] instanceof Array);
            console.log(typeof inputs[0][0]);

            total += input;
        }
    }
    else {
        for(input of inputs) {
            total += input;
        }
    }

    return total;        
}

console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
```

You can read more about the different for loops here (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been driving me insane. Also, you're lightning fast.

Comment: Anytime my friend. Good luck with what is next (y)